# Remove all character after matched character

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with many lines

```
http://example.com/part-1   this    number 1 one 
http://example.com/part--2  this is number 21 two
http://example.com/part10   this is an number 12 ten
http://example.com/part-num-11  this is an axample  number 212 eleven
```

How can I remove all character after "number x" + between first columd and "number x"...I wanna my output like this

```
http://example.com/part-1    1
http://example.com/part--2   21 
http://example.com/part10    12
http://example.com/part-num-11   212
```

Another case : 
Input:

```
http://server1.example.com/00/part-1    this    number 1 one 
http://server2.example.com/1a/part--2   this is section 21 two two
http://server3.example.com/2014/5/part10    this is an Part 12 ten  ten ten
http://server5.example.com/2014/7/part-num-11   this is an PARt number 212 eleven
```

I wanna the same output....And the number is always in last numeric field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^([^0-9]*[0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/' file
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/part-1 1
http://example.com/part--2 21
http://example.com/part10 12
http://example.com/part-num-11 212
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
awk -F"number" '{split($1,a," ");split($2,b," ");print a[1],b[1]}' file
http://example.com/part-1 1
http://example.com/part--2 21
http://example.com/part10 12
http://example.com/part-num-11 212
```

If the number you like to have is always on the second last field, this should do too:

```
awk '{print $1,$(NF-1)}' file
http://example.com/part-1 1
http://example.com/part--2 21
http://example.com/part10 12
http://example.com/part-num-11 212
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/ .*number \([0-9]+\).*/ \1/' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone...From your comments, I have my own solution :

```
sed -re 's/([0-9]*[0-9]+)/#\1#/g' | sed -re 's/(^.*#).*/\1/g' | sed 's/#//g' | awk '{print $1"  "$NF}'
```

My idea : Replace all numeric group with #[numbers]# , then select all character from start of line to "#" (sed will select last # ) and remove all rest character. Next is awk

Thank everyone (y)

Comment: No. Chaining a bunch of commands and pipes together for such a trivial thing is NOT the right approach. Use any of the other solutions posted and if you don't like either of those tells us as there's several other trivial single command solutions too.

Comment: My real cases are more complicate than this and include unicode string in every line....

Comment: And a chain of separate commands piped together somehow helps you with that compared to using one command?

Comment: What do I want in second example : First column and column with number...But the columns with number are difference on every lines...So, do you have any solution for my case?

Comment: Im sorry but i have no idea what youre talking about.

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my native language...And this is my real case http://i.imgur.com/p7qAJev.png (I replaced domain name) ....My task is get all links (example : http://example.com/read.php/982.htm )and numbers ( #499), put it into a file with 2 columns.

Comment: no problem, its not mine either. I'm not going to look at images and/or external links. If it's too lengthy/complicated to capture in a question then it's too lengthy/complicated for me to spend as much time as I'm willing to spend on it.