# How to get 1st column and last numeric column

Tags: awk, sed, grep

This is real case for my question in this topic ([Remove all character after matched character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211825/remove-all-character-after-matched-character/))

```
http://example.com/read.php/984.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     499-3 [TV] 
http://example.com/read.php/983.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     499-2 [TV] 
http://example.com/read.php/982.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     499 [TV] 
http://example.com/read.php/981.htm" target="_blank"> chapter 498 TV :11 siÃªu                     tÃ¢n tinh 
http://example.com/read.php/980.htm" target="_blank"> chapter 497 TV :cuá»™c                     phiÃªu lÆ°u táº¡i Ä‘áº£o bong bÃ³ng 
http://example.com/read.php/979.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     496 [TV] 
http://example.com/read.php/978.htm" target="_blank"> chapter 495 
http://example.com/read.php/977.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c)                     494 
http://example.com/read.php/976.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) section                     493 [TV] 
http://example.com/read.php/975.htm" target="_blank">s chapter 492 TV " Duval                     máº·t náº¡ sáº¯t" 
http://example.com/read.php/973.htm" target="_blank"> chap 490: Trá»Ÿ vá» nÆ¡i                     áº¥y. 
http://example.com/read.php/972.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     489 
http://example.com/read.php/971.htm" target="_blank"> 488 :BÃ i hÃ¡t cá»§a                     cuá»™c sá»‘ng 
http://example.com/read.php/970.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     487 
http://example.com/read.php/969.htm" target="_blank"> chao 486 CÃ¢y ÄÃ n                     DÆ°Æ¡ng Cáº§m 
http://example.com/read.php/968.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     485 
http://example.com/read.php/967.htm" target="_blank"> Part 484 
http://example.com/read.php/966.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) 483 
http://example.com/read.php/965.htm" target="_blank"> chap 482 
http://example.com/read.php/963.htm" target="_blank"> chapter 480
http://example.com/read.php/962.htm" target="_blank"> Chap 479 
http://example.com/read.php/961.htm" target="_blank"> Chap 478 
http://example.com/read.php/960.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     477 
http://example.com/read.php/959.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     476 
http://example.com/read.php/958.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     475 
http://example.com/read.php/957.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     474 
http://example.com/read.php/956.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     473 
http://example.com/read.php/955.htm" target="_blank"> (Ä‘áº£o háº£i táº·c) chap                     472 
http://example.com/read.php/954.htm" target="_blank"> chap 471 
http://example.com/read.php/953.htm" target="_blank"> chap 470 
http://example.com/read.php/952.htm" target="_blank"> chap 469 (tiáº¿p theo                     NXB) 
http://example.com/post/6050/" target="_blank"> chap-0 (Strong World)
```

How can I remove all character after "number x" + between first columd and "number x"...I wanna my output like this

```
http://example.com/read.php/982.htm 499-3
http://example.com/read.php/982.htm 499-2
http://example.com/read.php/982.htm 499 
http://example.com/read.php/981.htm 498 
http://example.com/read.php/980.htm 497 
http://example.com/read.php/979.htm 496 
http://example.com/read.php/978.htm 495 
http://example.com/read.php/977.htm 494
```

Note : "number x" sometime are 499-1 499-2 499-3

Comment: Writing code would be a good start...

Comment: to potential solvers: note that `number x` is NOT always the last element on the line. Good luck to all.

Comment: if `"number x" sometime are 499-1 499-2 499-3` then SHOW those in your sample input, that is the point of it. Also make sure your expected output is EXACTLY what youd expect given that input - it looks to me like some lines are missing.

Comment: What do you like to get out from the last line? `http://example.com/post/6050/" target="_blank"> chap-0 (Strong World)`  -> `http://example.com/post/6050/ 0`

Comment: @Ed Morton, the origin input is very long, and "499-1 499-2 499-3" is not common (about 8% chance to appear) so this input don't have. Last line "http://example.com/post/6050/ 0"  is needed too (another rare case)...The input is unpredictable, the only thing I knew that the input always have first column is hyperlink and the last numeric column

Comment: @Kim - YOU provide the input so just edit your question to include the relevant examples, you don't need to rely on whatever file you have lying around just happening to have a good sample. Its especially important to include every rare case you can think of as otherwise you'll get a script that only works for the common cases and fails at the first rare case, i.e. is useless. And make sure the expected output you post exactly matches in every line what you would specifically want output given that input file.

Answer (score 1):

by sed

```
sed -n 's/\(.*htm\)"[^0-9]*\( [-0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/p' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/(.*htm)"[^0-9]*( [-0-9]*).*/$1 $2/; print $_' < mydata
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=htm)\D*(\d+).*/ $1/' file
```